# Haskell module not found. What is wrong with my project's file structure?

Tags: haskell, import, module, project-structure

I have a problem with my project structure:

```
pic-analysis-0.1/AlgTop/Data.hs
                        Functions.hs
                 PNGModify.hs
                 Main.hs
```

**`Data.hs`:**

```
module AlgTop.Data (…) where
```

**`Functions.hs`:**

```
module AlgTop.Functions (…) where
import AlgTop.Data
```

The `AlgTop.Functions` module doesn't find `AlgTop.Data`.

I compared my project structure approach with that of `ansi-terminal` on Hackage (see below), but I couldn't spot any difference. What am I doing wrong?

```
ansi-terminal-xxx/System/Console/ANSI/Common.hs
                                     /Unix.hs
                                     /…
```

**`Common.hs`:**

```
module System.Console.ANSI.Common where
```

**`Unix.hs`:**

```
module System.Console.ANSI.Unix (…) where
import System.Console.ANSI.Common
```

---

Error message:

```
[...]
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *Functions.hs

Functions.hs:9:8:
    Could not find module `AlgTop.Data':
      locations searched:
        AlgTop/Data.hs
        AlgTop/Data.lhs
[...]
```

Comment: How are you importing `AlgTop.Functions`?

Comment: Are you loading the modules with ghci, or trying to compile the project with cabal?  Posting the actual error message may be useful.

Comment: `AlgTop.Functions` is another auxiliary module - providing boundary operator and other functions - my `Main` is to be programmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ghci it is probably that you need to `:set -i/.../pic-analysis-0.1`.  That is, include the root directory of your module hierarchy.

Comment: aah - i'm so dumb sometimes - i use runhaskell and a syntax checker in vim that complains all the time - because of this

Answer (score 4):

No need to set anything.  Just cd into the root directory before invoking GHCi:

```
ghci AlgTop/Functions.hs
```